# Strip double quotes from a string

Tags: vb.net

Here's my problem :

```
"p1".FillColor = Color.Gray
```

The goal is :

```
p1.FillColor = Color.Gray
```

Comment: And the usual bits follow... what have you tried?

Comment: can you specify what is p1?

Comment: it is the name of the rectangle shape

Comment: I love questions that mix VB6 with VB.NET and don't give a clue on what is the one right

Answer (score 1):

You cannot magically convert the *string literal* `"p1"` in to the identifier `p1`, instead use the string name to locate the control:

VB6: `Me.Controls("p1").FillColor = whatever`

VB.Net:

```
CType(Me.Controls.Find("p1", True)(0), XXX).FillColor = Color.Gray
```

where `XXX` is the type name of the control

Comment: what type of control is an rectangle shape?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(TypeName(p1))`

Comment: it says index out of bounce

Comment: Are you sure there is control named p1 on the form?